# Bootstrap 3 remove modal trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal which I use to sign users in or sign them up to my site. I also allow joining through Facebook.

Now, when a native session expires on my site, I don't want to automatically sign the user in through Facebook unless they distinctly tell me to, which means that I am triggering the sign-in when they click the link which triggers the modal.

The problem I am having is that the modal still fires (and then gets hidden straight away) and I was wondering if there was a way in which I could remove the modal trigger if the user has connected through Facebook, and instead, when they click the modal trigger it just signs them in.

I have tried this to no avail.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        $('#sidebar-auth-modal-trigger').off('click.bs.modal.data-api');
        $(document).off('click.bs.modal.data-api', '#sidebar-auth-modal-trigger');

        ...

    }
});
```

Comment: How are you triggering the modal?  Using their data attributes, or calling it on your own?

Comment: @cjd82187 Using data attributes

Comment: I'm not sure how you can turn those data-attributes off, but I'll give an example as an answer using their javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned you're using their data-attributes, remove that from your html.

Try only triggering the modal when your FB status is what you want, like this (I don't really know what your FB login status is doing, not all the code is there, but this should get you on your way):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
       //dont call your modal here if you dont want it

    } else {
        //call your modal
        $('#myModal').modal();
    } 

});

$('#sidebar-auth-modal-trigger').on('click', FB.getLoginStatus);
```

Now it will only call the modal when your facebook status is what you want it to be, and it won't when its not.

Comment: Awesome... kinda. It only worked in an anonymous function (see my edit)

Comment: also, the login status was sending the request to my API logging the user in on my server with AJAX, I didn't add the code because it was non-critical.

Comment: Saw your edit just now, but it was already rejected, not sure why.  Glad it got you pointed in the right direction though.